# Is the definition of continuity in analysis a particular case of topological continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Take a constant function and remove an open interval from it:

$$f(x)=
1,   \text{if $x\in(-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty)$ }$$

This function shouldn't be continuous because at $0$ no right limit of the function exists.

On the other hand, it's image is just $\mathrm{Im}f=1$. Since this is a closed set,the inverse image of every open set is an open set (because there are none). This means that $f$ is continuous.

Is there any mistake? Shouldn't both definitions coincide?

Comment: The function is continuous, including at 0 and 1. What is the argument that it is not, precisely?

Comment: The $\epsilon \delta$ definition should take into account the domain of the function: for any $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that $x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0+ \delta) \cap D \rightarrow f(x)\in (f(x_0)-\epsilon, f(x_0)+ \epsilon)$ where D is the domain

Comment: @Did  I thought $f(0+\delta)$,  $\delta>0$ had to be "close" to $f(0)$. But $f(\delta)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you use an incorrect epsilon-delta definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two definitions coincide (and every constant function is continuous on its domain of definition).

Recall that, for every $D\subseteq\mathbb R$, the epsilon-delta definition of some function $f:D\to\mathbb R$ being continuous at $x_0$ in $D$ is that $$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\quad \exists\delta\gt0,\quad \underline{\forall x\in D},\quad |x-x_0|\lt\delta\implies|f(x)-f(x_0)|\lt\varepsilon.$$ To replace in this definition the underlined part by $\forall x\in \mathbb R$ is absurd if $D\ne\mathbb R$.

> Since (...) $\mathrm{Im}(f)=\{1\}$ (...) is a closed set, the inverse image of every open set is an open set (because there are none). This means that $f$ is continuous.

This rendition of the "topological" definition of continuity is faulty. There are open sets, plenty of them, but the question is whether $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open set $U$ (and then $f$ is continuous), or not. In the present case, the remark that $\mathrm{Im}(f)=\{1\}$ is useful only because of its consequence below.

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\mathrm{Im}(f)=\{1\}$ and let $U$ be open.

- Either $U$ contains $1$, then $f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb R$, which is open.
- Or, $U$ does not contain $1$,  then $f^{-1}(U)=\varnothing$, which is open.

Thus $f$ is indeed continuous, and this has nothing to do with the fact that $\{1\}$ is closed.

To check that you got the point, let me suggest that you solve the following exercise:

> Let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\mathrm{Im}(g)=\{1,2\}$. Show that there exists some $x_0$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $g$ is **not** continuous at $x_0$.

And yet, $\{1,2\}$ is closed...

Comment: I have another doubt. With the topological definition, shouldn't the step function be continuous? Since its image is closed.

Comment: The image being closed is squarely offtopic, see the expanded version of my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've found my error. A real function is supposed to be $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$, but I was thinking of $f:D\to\mathrm{Im}f$, so I could only compute $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Im}f)$ and $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$. Still, I don't see how a constant function on a non-open domain is continuous. Say: $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, then if $U$ is an open set containing  $\mathrm{Im}f$,  $f^{-1}(U)=[0,1]$, which is closed.

Comment: But [0,1] is also open in [0,1] since [0,1] contains a neighborhood in [0,1] of each of its points, namely, [0,1] itself.

Comment: I've got it now, I wasn't taking into account that openess depends on the space we are working in.

Comment: Indeed it does.